# after adding vue3 the npm run serve does not work

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

i have a typescript project with vue
and after this

```
vue add vue-next
```

the project can not run with

```
npm run serve
```

the error given is:

```
Error: Cannot find module '@vue/compiler-sfc/package.json'
```

Comment: can you share the repo for this?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a package vue3 requires.

Run:

```
npm install --save-dev @vue/compiler-sfc
```

Then:

```
npm run serve
```